# selenium can't find class

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, c#

I'm using selenium and can't find this class

`var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class, 'rc-imageselect-table-33')]")).Text; //works`

from this link https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/

and the html has the class
http://prntscr.com/d3co2r

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

`driver.findElement(By.CssLocator("img.rc-image-tile-33")).Text`

and if this doesn't work try to put a parent container in front of the locator.
Example

`"#tableID img.rc-image-tile-33"`

Probably somewhere on the page there is another img with the same class name.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d3eii7

only one http://prntscr.com/d3ejos
doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try please try this:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rc-imageselect-table-33");
```

Because most of the times finding an element through xpath can be a difficult.

Comment: not works ( can u try it !

Comment: Can you be specific about what do you want to do with that image, do you want to click, the specific images in the capatcha?

Comment: i want catch element to can download it and click it ,i hope u can help

Comment: I came to know that my solution was failing because all the respective individual images have the same class name.

Comment: as you see http://prntscr.com/d3e38l
it's only 1 class and i want catch it to can take screenshopt then click to box !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check it if these image are inside an iframe node? If it is the case, you should switch first to the iframe. You should share more piece of your HTML. Then. I will be able to help more appropriately.